# How to combine cell D2 and cell C2 values in a formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Line D is a date value and I want to combine "D2" and "C2" values.

I cannot get the formula. I tried adding quotes and spacing between the "&".

```
Sub insertValue()
    Range("A1").Value = "id"    'integer
    Range("B1").Value = "money"    'integer
    Range("C1").Value = "Note"    'string
    Range("E2").Formula = =c2 &"" "" & TEXT(d2,"mm/dd/yyyy")    'error on this line
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("E2").Formula = "=c2 &"" "" & TEXT(d2,""mm/dd/yyyy"")"`

Comment: That did the trick, so adding extra quotes is what was needed? Thank you so much.